# virtualhost not working in postman but accessible thru CURL

Tags: server, apache2, php, virtualhost, slim

I'm using SLIM framework that I can access using local url: http://localhost:/

but I can't access it thru virtualhost by entering the url: http://dev.slim.com in browser or in postman. It says:

**This site can’t be reache dev.slim.com’s server IP address could not be found.**

Here is my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName dev.slim.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api-slim/public/

<Directory /var/www/html/api-slim/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

and yet I tried using CURL and I've got some results from the url, which means the virtualhost is working but how come I can't access it in browser or in postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working by following the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986676/ubuntu-apache-virtual-host-site-doesnt-work-in-the-browser

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) and also .com  to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.